# fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder in MailCore2 does not always return the last N number of emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

On most folders, fetchMessagesByNumber works as expected. If I expect to get the latest 40 messages in a folder, it will grab around 35-40. I'm assuming that the reason why I don't always get 40/40 is that the sequence numbers are not always sequential in Gmail (??).

However, on one of my inbox's "All folder" in Gmail which has about 43,000 emails, the fetchMessagesByNumber almost always returns no messages. If "messagesToGet" is 10, 100, 500, it will return no messages.

It's not until I try to retrieve the last 3000 messages that it return any emails.

What assumptions and I making that are incorrect with "fetchMessagesByNumber" and my range?

```
MCOIndexSet *numbers = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake([info messageCount] - messagesToGet, messagesToGet)];

folderSync = [_imapSession
         fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder:@"[Gmail]/All Mail"
         requestKind:requestKind
         numbers:numbers];
```

In order to circumvent this, I have used the other query instead, but the problem with querying on a UID range is that theoretically it is more inaccurate as UIDs are not guaranteed to be sequential. Ideally, I would like to use the above query but can't get it working.

```
MCOIndexSet *numbers = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(lastUID - messagesToGet, messagesToGet)];

folderSync = [_imapSession
         fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:@"[Gmail]/All Mail"
         requestKind:requestKind
         uids:numbers];
```

**EDIT:**

I figured out why my method isn't returning the expected # of messages. I'm using MCOIMAPFolderStatusOperation instead of MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation.

I thought these two commands were interchangeable as they both return [info messageCount]. I opted to use the former to be able to access the status.highestModSeqValue property.

HOWEVER, it turns out MCOIMAPFolderStatusOperation returns a messageCount of 44514 whereas MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation returns a messageCount of 42459.

Is this expected? Here are the logs for both. This one is for MCOIMAPFolderStatusOperation:

```
2015-03-12 23:02:31.435 iOS UI Test[5529:4648946] checking account
2015-03-12 23:02:31.436 [5529:560f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:81: start thread
2015-03-12 23:02:31.442 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:569: connect <mailcore::IMAPSession:0x7fa043d5d0f0>
2015-03-12 23:02:31.772 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 98.248.43.119 hl7mb54795112pad
2015-03-12 23:02:31.772 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:592: ssl connect imap.gmail.com 993 2
2015-03-12 23:02:31.774 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 1 CAPABILITY
2015-03-12 23:02:31.823 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
1 OK Thats all she wrote! hl7mb54795112pad
2015-03-12 23:02:31.823 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:649: connect ok
2015-03-12 23:02:31.823 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:689: login
2015-03-12 23:02:31.984 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
2 OK vu0tran@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
2015-03-12 23:02:31.984 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 3 COMPRESS DEFLATE
2015-03-12 23:02:32.043 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: 3 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.043 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 4 ENABLE CONDSTORE
2015-03-12 23:02:32.098 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * ENABLED CONDSTORE
4 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.099 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 5 NAMESPACE
2015-03-12 23:02:32.151 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
5 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.151 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 6 ID NIL
2015-03-12 23:02:32.208 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * ID ("name" "GImap" "vendor" "Google, Inc." "support-url" "http://support.google.com/mail" "version" "gmail_imap_150308.09_p0" "remote-host" "98.248.43.119")
6 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.208 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:935: login ok
2015-03-12 23:02:32.208 iOS UI Test[5529:4648946] finished checking account.
2015-03-12 23:02:32.209 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1063: status
2015-03-12 23:02:32.209 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 7 STATUS "[Gmail]/All Mail" (UNSEEN MESSAGES RECENT UIDNEXT UIDVALIDITY HIGHESTMODSEQ)
2015-03-12 23:02:32.265 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * STATUS "[Gmail]/All Mail" (HIGHESTMODSEQ 4084511 MESSAGES 44514 RECENT 0 UIDNEXT 64049 UIDVALIDITY 612907046 UNSEEN 10719)
7 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.266 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1086: status error : 0
2015-03-12 23:02:32.266 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:994: select
2015-03-12 23:02:32.266 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 8 SELECT "[Gmail]/All Mail"
2015-03-12 23:02:32.762 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $Forwarded JunkRecorded $NotJunk NotJunk $NotPhishing $Junk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $Forwarded JunkRecorded $NotJunk NotJunk $NotPhishing $Junk \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 612907046] UIDs valid.
* 42488 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 64049] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4084511]
8 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/All Mail selected. (Success)
2015-03-12 23:02:32.762 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:998: select error : 0
2015-03-12 23:02:32.762 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1052: select ok
2015-03-12 23:02:32.762 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2178: request flags
2015-03-12 23:02:32.763 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2229: request envelope
2015-03-12 23:02:32.763 [5529:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2251: request bodystructure
2015-03-12 23:02:32.763 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 1 withData: 9 FETCH 44505:44514 (UID FLAGS ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE INTERNALDATE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (References Subject)])
2015-03-12 23:02:32.799 iOS UI Test[5529:4649416] event logged:0x7fa043d58870 0 withData: 9 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:02:32.800 iOS UI Test[5529:4648946] fetched all messages.
2015-03-12 23:02:33.899 [5529:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:215: trying to quit 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:02:33.899 [5529:560f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:102: stopping 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:02:33.899 [5529:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:230: thread stopped 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:02:33.899 [5529:560f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:151: cleanup thread 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:03:03.899 [5529:5313] MCOperationQueue.cpp:81: start thread
2015-03-12 23:03:04.980 [5529:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:215: trying to quit 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:03:04.980 [5529:5313] MCOperationQueue.cpp:102: stopping 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:03:04.981 [5529:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:230: thread stopped 0x7fa043d605f0
2015-03-12 23:03:04.981 [5529:5313] MCOperationQueue.cpp:151: cleanup thread 0x7fa043d605f0
```

This one is for MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation:

```
2015-03-12 23:09:11.390 iOS UI Test[8138:4681733] checking account
2015-03-12 23:09:11.391 [8138:560f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:81: start thread
2015-03-12 23:09:11.396 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:569: connect <mailcore::IMAPSession:0x7fcfb31218d0>
2015-03-12 23:09:11.767 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 98.248.43.119 cm1mb31383387pbc
2015-03-12 23:09:11.767 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:592: ssl connect imap.gmail.com 993 2
2015-03-12 23:09:11.769 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 1 CAPABILITY
2015-03-12 23:09:11.824 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
1 OK Thats all she wrote! cm1mb31383387pbc
2015-03-12 23:09:11.824 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:649: connect ok
2015-03-12 23:09:11.824 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:689: login
2015-03-12 23:09:11.907 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
2 OK vu0tran@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
2015-03-12 23:09:11.907 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 3 COMPRESS DEFLATE
2015-03-12 23:09:11.959 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: 3 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:09:11.960 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 4 ENABLE CONDSTORE
2015-03-12 23:09:12.012 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * ENABLED CONDSTORE
4 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:09:12.013 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 5 NAMESPACE
2015-03-12 23:09:12.069 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
5 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:09:12.070 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 6 ID NIL
2015-03-12 23:09:12.123 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * ID ("name" "GImap" "vendor" "Google, Inc." "support-url" "http://support.google.com/mail" "version" "gmail_imap_150308.09_p0" "remote-host" "98.248.43.119
2015-03-12 23:09:12.124 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: ")
6 OK Success
2015-03-12 23:09:12.124 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:935: login ok
2015-03-12 23:09:12.124 iOS UI Test[8138:4681733] finished checking account.
2015-03-12 23:09:12.124 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:994: select
2015-03-12 23:09:12.124 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 7 SELECT "[Gmail]/All Mail"
2015-03-12 23:09:12.620 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 0 withData: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $Forwarded JunkRecorded $NotJunk NotJunk $NotPhishing $Junk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $Forwarded JunkRecorded $NotJunk NotJunk $NotPhishing $Junk \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 612907046] UIDs valid.
* 42488 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 64049] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4084511]
7 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/All Mail selected. (Success)
2015-03-12 23:09:12.620 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:998: select error : 0
2015-03-12 23:09:12.620 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1052: select ok
2015-03-12 23:09:12.621 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2178: request flags
2015-03-12 23:09:12.621 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2229: request envelope
2015-03-12 23:09:12.621 [8138:560f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:2251: request bodystructure
2015-03-12 23:09:12.621 iOS UI Test[8138:4682226] event logged:0x7fcfb311d980 1 withData: 8 FETCH 42479:42488 (UID FLAGS ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE INTERNALDATE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (References Subject)])
```

Comment: Could you show the connection logger logs?

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I edited my question to include the connection logger. Let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: I think some part of the log is missing. Has the folder been selected before?

Comment: I updated it again. Does any of that help?

Comment: 1. I can't see the status operation in your code. 2. I can't see the logs of the FETCH command.

Comment: Hey @DinhViêtHoà. I updated the logs. Seems like MCOIMAPFolderStatusOperation returns a different messageCount than  MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation? 

Is this expected?

Comment: Yes. I usually don't trust the response of STATUS.